# Is there a way to make Illustrator preserve path's curvature when removing anchor points like Corel DRAW

Tags: adobe-illustrator, corel-draw, bezier-curve

When refining a vector in CorelDRAW and node(s) get removed from it, CorelDRAW preserves vector's curvature (as much as possible), but when removing anchor points on Illustrator paths, it destroys the curvature.

Is there any tool, plug-in or script out there to make this procedure possible in Illustrator, same as CorelDRAW ?

**CorelDRAW**

[image: **CorelDRAW**]

**Adobe Illustrator**

[image: **Adobe Illustrator**]

Comment: Vetorscribe is probably your best option for simplifying paths.

Comment: thx welz I'll try that.

Comment: Yes ... as far as I'm aware **VectorScribe**, specifically the **InkScribe** portion, is the only way I know.

Comment: I would say... Keep using Corel Draw... Xo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try holding down the shift key while using the delete anchor point tool. It retains the curvature of the path! Works in newer versions of Illustrator.

Comment: I'm on Illustrator CC, and sadly I cannot confirm that this workflow is successful at all - I tried it, and cannot see any difference between the results of removing an anchor with versus without **Shift** held down: in all cases, the net curve is substantially altered.

Comment: It works in CC2020 v23.4 which I got it now - Seems like other ones have trouble with this feature, but it has been added since 2020 and works well!

Comment: You need to select the Delete Anchor Point tool directly ("-" shortcut), it won't work if you try using the Pen Tool on top of an existing point (which temporarily switches to the Delete Anchor Point tool). Kinda misleading I know, but there you have it.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to remove anchor points on Illustrator is the Simplify window.

Object > Path > Simplify

You can reduce vector points after selecting the path with WYSIWIG info. If you get familiar with this tool, the result could get better than the original path.

[image: window]

You can also use this window selecting just some points with the Direct Selection Tool (the white pointer).

Comment: If you want to remove one point, select this point, the one before and the one after with the Direct Selection Tool, as is mentioned on the answer, and open the Simplify window.

Comment: @Daniello good point, I hadn't thought of that +1

Comment: Yes simplify is a handy one. but this not gonna change curvature editing algorithm which I asked about. touching sometimes needs a more accurate and manual work. In corelDRAW there is "Reduce nodes" slider like "Simplify" in AI but CDR beside that haves a good curve keeping algorithm, and I think I gonna submit some feature request! thx

Comment: I updated and feature I asked for has been added, seems like in CC2020 24.x - Use "Remove anchor point" tool (pen with a minus) and hold shift while removing by click on anchor points, it preserves curvature as much as it could, thank you btw for this answer, I kept using your method 'till now! XD

Answer (score 2):

Removing single points while keeping the path is not possible in Illustrator without plugins.

Possible plugins as mentioned [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18264/illustrator-delete-points-but-keep-curves):

- [VectorScribe](https://astutegraphics.com/software/vectorscribe/)
- [InkScribe](https://astutegraphics.com/software/inkscribe/)

For simply reducing the points in a path, there is the **Simplify Tool** `Object > Path > Simplify` where you can reduce the points in a path by simply dragging a slider. Usually, adjusting the precision just a little bit reduces the amount of points in a given path a lot, if the path was drawn by hand for example.

[image: Illustrator Simplify Tool]

Comment: I updated and feature added seems like in CC2020 24.x - if you remove anchor points with "Remove anchor point" tool (pen with a minus) and hold shift while removing by click on anchor points it preserves curvature as much as it could, very similar in CorelDRAW! and thank you btw for this answer, I kept using your method 'till now! XD

Answer (score -1):

I tried to find the way to do this in Illustrator without any success. My solution is I bought Affinity Designer which is very affordable and use ( Ctrl Alt Backspace ) to delete nodes/anchor points.

https://affinity.serif.com/en-us/

Here is my way to make complex curve smooth

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gCYuNmaTJho

Comment: I already compared one another software with AI, CorelDRAW as the post title says.
I think it's not a good idea to try other software! I want a solution within AI!!!

Answer (score -2):

The new Illustrator 2020 used to do when you press and hold the shift key along with the delete  point tool. but strangely enough it stops and went back to it’s old function suddenly. 
I reinstalled the software and the function worked well for a while then it stopped again.

Comment: I think I will give it a try!

Comment: It is added since CC2020 v24.3 - I updated recently - Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score -3):

Or export to SVG, open in Inkscape (free) and delete the point(s) :)

Comment: the question is specific about doing it in Illustrator...

Comment: The post is about a feature to be within AI!