# Illustrator - How can I clean extra path point?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Please as stated above in the title, how can I clean up extra points in a path? keeping only the extrem points that holds a path inbetween?

[image]

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Select them with the **Direct Selection Tool** (white arrow), then click the **Minus Anchor Point** button on the Control bar.

[image]

Note that for *curves* it's way more problematic.

See here: [Illustrator - Delete points but keep curves](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18264/illustrator-delete-points-but-keep-curves)

Comment: For curves, select a path, then use Path, Simplify Path. If you go too far on multiple simplify clicks, use Undo to back as much as required

Comment: If this is a regular task I'd recommend a look into the Astute Plugins, as recommended in one of the answers in the linked thread. Also these plugins are free for a 2 weeks trial.