# Adobe Illustrator - mantain path shape after erasing vertex

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, path, stroke, brush

issue:
After I draw a path with the Paintbrush Tool, if I erase part of the path, the whole curve changes its shape slightly

what I want to achieve:
I want to be able to erase part of the path I've drawn without this affecting the overall shape of it

in other questions a few addons were suggested, but the links are outdated or the addons don't exist anymore
[Illustrator - Delete points but keep curves](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18264/illustrator-delete-points-but-keep-curves)

Comment: The pluggins are still there, vectorscribe and inkscribe. Just go to https://astutegraphics.com/ and click on the plugins drop down, and you will find them.

Comment: I edited that answer with a viable link again. The old links merely rotted away due to web site updates at Astute. Products are still there: https://astutegraphics.com/plugins/vectorscribe